# Error codigo python (linea 4)

Tags: python

Tengo un error de sintaxis en la linea 4 del codigo, en el print. Ayuda porfavor.

```
a=float(input('Introduzca una nota del 0 al 10: ')

if 0<=a>5 
   print('Suspendido')
elif 5<=a>8 
  print('Aprobado')
elif 8<=a>9.5 
  print('Notable')
elif 9.5<=a>=10
  print('Sobresaliente')
else :
  print('La nota introducida no es válida')
```

Comment: Te falta un paréntesis de cierre en la linea del `input` y te faltan los `:` después de cada expresión condicional,`if 0<=a>5 :`, `elif 5<=a>8:` ..., igual que tienes en el `else`. Usa siempre cuatro espacios para identar

Comment: Además de los errores de sintaxis la lógica está mal, los intervalos no son correctos, `0<=a>5` valida que a sea mayor o igual que 0 y ¿mayor que 5? Debe ser `0 <= a < 5` (a mayor o igual que cero y menor a 5). Lo mismo para el resto.